# CSS Footer Styling

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am working on a WordPress site that was built by someone else, and currently I'm trying to style the footer and am having some problems.

First of all, it won't let my style by selecting any of the divs in the  tag, It will only work if I directly select the html element (footer [role=contentinfo] p {...}), and even this is spotty.

Can anyone provide some guidance? Here is the footer code

```
  <?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the footer.
 *
 * Contains footer content and the closing of the
 * #main and #page div elements.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twelve
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */
?>
    </div><!-- #main .wrapper -->
    <footer id="colophon" role="contentinfo">
        <div class="footer-links">
            <ul>
                <li>About</li>
                <li>About JoeStick</li>
                <li>Our Products</li>
                <li>FAQs</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="site-info">
            <p>YOU MUST BE OVER THE AGE OF 18 YEARS TO BUY AND OR USE ANY SOUTH BEACH SMOKE PRODUCT. Nicotine is a highly addictive
            substance derived from the tobacco plant. Our products do not treat, diagnose, or cure any disease, physical ailment, or
            condition. If you are allergic to nicotene or any combination or inhalents, if you are pregnant or breast-feeding, or if
            you have a heart condition, diabetes, high blood pressure or asthma, consult your physician before using South Beach Smoke
            nicotene products. Just like traditional tobacco cigarettes, South Beach Smoke Electronic Cegiarettes are not approved by
            the American FDA.</p>
        </div><!-- .site-info -->
        <div class="footer-nav">
            <ol>
                <li>Copyright &copy; 2013 SmokeSafely.com</li>
                <li>Terms and Conditions</li>
                <li>Warnings</li>
                <li>Privacy Policy</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </footer><!-- #colophon -->
</div><!-- #page -->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the CSS I'm trying to use

```
/* Footer */
}
footer[role="contentinfo"] {
    background-color: #082448;
    color: white;
    border-top: 1px solid #ededed;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 2;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
footer[role="contentinfo"] a {
    color: #686868;
}
footer[role="contentinfo"] a:hover {
    color: #21759b;
}
footer[role="contentinfo"] ul {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
}
footer[role="contentinfo"] p {
    width: 65%;
    height: 30%;
    float: left;
    font-size: 10px;
}
footer[role="contentinfo"] ol {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5%;
    float: none;
}
footer[role="contentinfo"] ol li {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}
```

Currently the main thing I'm struggling with is the background color on the footer not displaying correctly. Again, any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the footer tag with the id:

```
#colophon {background-color:red;}
```

...or whatever you want it to change to.

Sometimes wordpress overwrites those rules, so I use (I know, I am sure this is horrible practice, but it gets the job done.)

```
#colophon {background-color:red !important;}
```

Then to grab certain parts of the document, you can use the [child selector.](http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200006b.html)

```
#colophon > div > ul > li {background-color:red;}
```

I hope this helps!